# Add Network Adapter to VM in vCloud Director using PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, virtualization, powercli, vmware-vcloud-director

I am using the PowerCLI version 12 and have a VM which currently has no network adapter.

There is the Cmdlet `Get-CINetworkAdapter` but that returns null (because there is no adapter)
And there is `Set-CINetworkAdapter` but again without a CINetworkAdapter to pass in this doesn't work.

Is there a `New-CINetworkAdapter` I am missing somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently the code I am using to do this:

```
$NIC = New-Object -TypeName 'VMware.VimAutomation.Cloud.Views.OvfRASD'
$NIC.AddressOnParent = '0'
$NIC.AutomaticAllocation = New-Object -TypeName 'VMware.VimAutomation.Cloud.Views.CimBoolean'
$NIC.AutomaticAllocation.Value = $true
$NICConnectionString = New-Object -TypeName 'VMware.VimAutomation.Cloud.Views.CimString'
$connectionAttributes = New-Object 'VMware.VimAutomation.Cloud.Views.XmlAttributeCollection'
$connectionAttributes.Add('ns5','ipAddressingMode','http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5','POOL')
$connectionAttributes.Add('ns5','primaryNetworkConnection','http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5','true')
$NICConnectionString.AnyAttr = $connectionAttributes
$NICConnectionString.Value = 'None'
$NIC.Connection = $NICConnectionString
$NIC.Description = 'VMXNET3 ethernet adapter on ''none'''
$NIC.ElementName = 'Network adapter 0'
$NIC.InstanceID = '0'
$NIC.ResourceSubType = 'VMXNET3'
$NICResourceType = New-Object -TypeName 'VMware.VimAutomation.Cloud.Views.CimRASDResource'
$NICResourceType.Value = '10'
$NIC.ResourceType = $NICResourceType

$vm = Get-CIVM -Name '[VM Name]'
$vmVirtualHardwareSection = $vm.ExtensionData.GetVirtualHardwareSection()
$vmNetworkCards = $vmVirtualHardwareSection.GetNetworkCards()
$vmNetworkCards.Item = $NIC
$vmNetworkCards.UpdateServerData()
```